# Fix header using flex now working in ipad

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have following html structure.

```
<div className={css.mainContainer}>
  <div className={css.headerContainer}>  // fixed not scrollable
       //some content
  </div>
  <div className={css.attributeContainer}> // this needs to be fixed 
     <div className={css.attribute}>
       //some content
     </div>
   
     <div className={css.commentsContainer}>//some content needs to be scrollable
       
     </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, Here I am trying to make few divs scrollable and one with fixed header using flex

```
.mainContainer {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.headerContainer {
 height: 44px
}

.attributeContainer {
 display : flex
 flex-direction: column
 height: calc(100vh - 44px); // Not sure should we use this or flex:1
}

.attribute {
 // some font related styles
    
}

.commentsContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

These are the styles which I have applied for this.So, here on Laptop it makes the header fixed but in case of IPAD it does not whole tab is scrollable. can any one one help me with this ?

using safari browser on ipad .

Comment: Try adding `overflow: auto;` to `.attributeContainer` to make it scrollable. Also use `flex: 1` for *height* as that is more suitable given you have used it in other places, though it won't change anything.

Comment: Hi @isAif I have just updated the question attributeContainer this container also needs to be fixed just the inner div should be scrollable

Comment: And yes I have already added overflow auto

Comment: Hello @ganesh Can you add some kinda codepen link so that we can preview what you have. Because I couldn't understand because of there is no text in your html